What is the Teradata equivalent of FormatNumber()?
Below is an expression from SQL Server Reporting:
ToNumber(Left(FormatNumber([ColName];"00";1)) 

How to acheive this in Teradata?
I have tried the following:
CAST(SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR([ColName], '00') FROM 1 FOR 1) AS INTEGER)

But received the error below:
Failed [9881: HY000] Function 'TO_CHAR' called with an invalid number or type of parameters

What are you actually trying to do? Please include sample data and your desired output.

These will truncate a decimal to integer and then string TO_CHAR(CAST(your_decimal_column AS INTEGER)) AS string_value  or just integer CAST(your_decimal_column AS INTEGER) AS integer_value  if you need rounding add that

Show us some sample data and the expected result. (Don't expect Teradata users to know SQL Server stuff too.)

Your original expresion is malformed. Your attempt shown is syntactically invalid because you used SQL Server [ColName] syntax instead of standard "ColName". Also '00' is not a valid format string for TO_CHAR. Agree with the other commenters - tell us what is the intent and show us some examples; then someone can help you.
